# Lenovo Z40 laptop shows a black display screen after running a Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows

I am using a Lenovo Z40 first time I upgraded to Windows 10, I left the room for an hour and came back to a blank black screen. So I tried restarting the computer which didn’t do anything. 
I then tried hooking up my TV to my laptop which worked. The upgrade had failed so I thought reinstalling it might fix my laptop screen. So I installed Windows 10 successfully, but my laptop screen is still black and will only work with an external monitor/TV.

Sometimes I can see the screen of my laptop flicker. Will reverting back to windows 8.1 help me?

Comment: Is there a function key combo that switches to the laptop screen?  For example, mine is Fn + F8 to change to an external screen and back to the laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me for a while until I figured out that sometimes it goes to the lowest resolution screen/monitor.  In my case, it was a projector (that was off).  I have to physically disconnect the HDMI cable to stop it happening.  So, I would suggest that you try and turn off the external monitor when restarting or upgrading.